# Импорт нескольких диапазонов в Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Помогите с гуглотаблицами

Использую

```
=IMPORTRANGE("docID"; "SheetID!A:Z")
```

все работает, но если хочу вывести несколько диапазонов, например

```
=IMPORTRANGE("docID"; "SheetID!A:B,F:Z")
```

то вылезает ошибка «Не удалось найти диапазон или лист для импорта.»

Что я делаю не так? Как пофиксить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так сделать нельзя.

Нужно либо сформировать массив в источнике, это делается когда нужно скрыть данные для всех потребителей, либо обработать данные после получения.

### Если на стороне источника

1. Создайте новый лист в источнике, т.е. в Таблице с `docID`.
2. Добавьте на этот лист формулу

```
={SheetID!A:B\SheetID!F:Z}
```

<sup>**Примечание**: знаки конкатенации могут быть разными. См. [How to union ranges in google spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793321/how-to-union-ranges-in-google-spreadsheets/42488671#42488671)</sup>

3. Используйте импорт с этого листа

### Если на стороне приемника

1. Импортируйте весь диапазон `=IMPORTRANGE("docID"; "SheetID!A:Z")` на отдельный лист
2. Используйте прием с конкатенацией, описанный выше. Например, вы импортировали все на лист "ImportSheet", тогда нужный массив можно получить как

```
={ImportSheet!A:B\ImportSheet!F:Z}
```

Comment: Отлично! Это то, что нужно. Благодарю